# Уровень сигнала GPS спутника

Tags: android, gps

Доброго всем времени суток.
Пишу навигатор для Android. Есть необходимость показывать на экране уровень сигнала каждого спутника в виде прогресбара. В классе `GpsSatellite` есть для этого функция `getSnr()`. Она возвращает соотношение сигнала GPS к шуму. В пределах каких значений может быть результат этой функции?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460560/gpssatellite-getsnr-what-is-the-value-range
Посмотрите тут

Comment: @aldem67, там точно не указанно: написанно что 29 - очень сильный сигнал.(хотя моё устройство показывает больше),дальше сказано что предел для значений - 90, а по стандарту 'NMEA' вообще 99. Моё устройство в идеальных условиях выдаёт значения до 39. Не могу понятль какое значение считать как максимальное.